# How to create a matrix of evenly-spaced points within an angled polygon, given the corner coordinates [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, spatial

Given some example random data, with UTM coordinates for each corner:

```
       test<-structure(list(name = c("P11C1", "P11C2", "P11C3", "P11C4"), 
    east = c(6404807.016, 6404808.797, 6404786.695, 6404784.761
    ), north = c(497179.4834, 497159.1862, 497156.6599, 497176.4444
    ), plot_num = c(11, 11, 11, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If we plot this as a polygon. we can see a tilted rectangle (this is because this shape is generated using real differential-GPS captured coordinates on the ground):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test) + geom_polygon(aes(east, north))
```

[image: random rectangle]

- My question is, how can I generate points among custom dimensions
  that are evenly spaced within this polygon? For instance, if I want
  to generate a grid of evenly spaced 10x11 points within this grid. Can anyone suggest a neat to do this, given the corner points? I have hundreds of discrete plots for which I would then like to loop/map a solution over. I assume this
  involves some simple geometry, but with the added confusion of a
  tilted plot, I've gotten really confused and could not find a similar
  solution here on SO or elsewhere! FYI in this instance I am not
  expecting projection to be an issue since it is UTM coordinates, but
  a spatial solution that accounts for global projections would be cool
  to see, too!

Comment: On a guess, grids upon your discrete bounding boxes are different from the 'bulk' plot you currently display, that should give encouragement, i.e. 'PC11C1' is different from 'PC11C4', though currently they are not deemed extents (st_extent, I'm making that up till I research) by structure.  Does that wake you to a plausible solution in as much as you have four different bounding boxes here. The 'rotation' is immaterial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this little function:

```r
gridify <- function(x, y, grid_x = 10, grid_y = 10) {
  x <- sort(x)
  y <- sort(y)
  xvals <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(a, b) seq(b, a, length = grid_x),
      a = seq(x[1], x[3], length = grid_y), 
      b = seq(x[2], x[4], length = grid_y)))
  yvals <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(a, b) seq(a, b, length = grid_y),
                              a = seq(y[1], y[3], length = grid_x), 
                              b = seq(y[2], y[4], length = grid_x)))
  as.data.frame(cbind(x = c(xvals), y = c(t(yvals))))
}
```

So for example, to plot a 10 by 11 grid, we would do:

```r
ggplot(test) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(east, north)) +
  geom_point(data = gridify(x = test$east, y = test$north, grid_x = 11),
             aes(x, y), color = 'red') +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

And we can scale to arbitrary numbers of points:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(east, north)) +
  geom_point(data = gridify(x = test$east, y = test$north, 50, 50),
             aes(x, y), color = 'red') +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]